# tcpdf font ligatures (English)?

Tags: php, pdf, fonts, tcpdf, truetype

How do you generate ligatures in PHP tcpdf?

Answer (score 0):

tcpdf either uses FreeType to rasterize the fonts, or just embeds them into the PDF and they are rasterized in the viewer. Ligatures are actually defined in the fonts. If you are using a Type1 font and specify a ligature character in your string, Freetype will rasterize it. Automatic substitution of "fi", "ff" etc. for ligatures as in OpenType is not supported by FreeType, so I am guessing it won't be supported by tcpdf either. See http://www.adobe.com/devnet/opentype/archives/glyph.html for glyph names etc.

Comment: I have several font files where the ligatures are defined in another file.. day roman (roman), for example has romanx, with ligature definitions. any idea on how to integrate fonts with separate ligature definitions?

Comment: This is going to be pretty difficult I think - if you split the strings in PHP and replace "ff"'s "fi"s etc. with ligatures in a different font I am guessing this might screw up kerning pairs that the font has and it won't look too good. Kind of defeats the purpose. I am not even sure InDesign or Quark can work with a separate font for ligatures.